# HTTP Error 403 with php curl

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-403

I want to do a http request with curl but can't get a valid response from the server.

the `$url` variable is filled with the string: `"http://www.transfermarkt.de/borussia-dortmund/startseite/verein/16/index.html"`

```
function request($url) {

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $statuscode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $statustext = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($statuscode!=200){
    echo "HTTP ERROR ".$statuscode."<br>";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_dump($statustext);
    echo "</pre>";
    return "false";

    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I grouped the information you give to the top of the question and removed unnecessary information such as 'thanks'. also formatting code helps understanding faster what could be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That website checks for a valid `User-Agent` header which the cURL PHP client does not provide by default (though the commandline client does). To overcome that you can add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: curl/7.39.0');
```

or similar.

Edit: full code succesfully tested:

```
<?php

function request($url){
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: curl/7.39.0');

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $statuscode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        $statustext = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if($statuscode!=200){
        echo "HTTP ERROR ".$statuscode."<br>";
        echo "<pre>";
        echo var_dump($statustext);
        echo "</pre>";
        return "false";

        }
        return $result;
    }

echo request('http://www.transfermarkt.de/borussia-dortmund/startseite/verein/16/index.html');

?>
```

Comment: super answer "curl/7.39.0" is magical agent i dont know what is meaning of this agent but after testing 50-100 user agent only this works for me.thanks alot